# Does the new Omniauth 1.0.0 work with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm currently using: `gem "omniauth", '0.3.2'`

I'm trying to upgrade to omniauth 1.0.0 by replace the above with:

```
gem 'omniauth-github', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github.git' # Core, requires a OA Stratedgy gem for each provider
gem 'omniauth-facebook', :git => 'git://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook.git' # FB OmmiAuth Stratedgy
gem 'omniauth-contrib', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/omniauth-contrib.git' # TWITTER OmmiAuth Stratedgy
```

But I'm getting an error when I bundle install/update:

```
$ bundle install
Updating git://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github.git
Updating git://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook.git
Updating git://github.com/intridea/omniauth-contrib.git
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "hashie":
  In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
    hashie (1.1.0)

  In Gemfile:
    omniauth-facebook depends on
      hashie (~> 1.2)

Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, using only
the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "omniauth":
  In Gemfile:
    omniauth-contrib depends on
      omniauth (~> 1.0)

    omniauth-facebook depends on
      omniauth (1.0.0.rc2)
```

Suggestions? Thoughts? Thx

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue.  To use the omniauth-facebook gem, you need to have omniauth 1.0 installed like so in your Gemfile:

**gem "omniauth", '>=0.3.2'**

That and a **bundle update** solved the issue for me.

Comment: i had the same issue when running `bundle install` but had no problems when i ran `bundle update` instead. in addition, you might find this [article](http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/) helpful.